# Link to the SDK Bluetooth chat example

Tags: android, bluetooth

Can anyone give me a link to the eclipse project in zip format that contains the bluetooth chat example from the developer site [link to the example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html)? I tried to do it myself but im getting a bunch of errors and as I searched there are strange API level requirements too [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418264/error-in-the-sample-code-bluetooth-chat). How can it be possible to have API level 11 requirement in a project that is made in 2009?

I'm developing to API level 7 (2.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the samples for API level 7, use the android SDK and AVD manager.

Answer (score 2):

m also working on BlueTooth chat example, i just started new android project, and select project from existing source,, selected minimum API as Android API 2.1 updated for bluetooth chat example.

& for the complete source folder, u can goto android-sdk-windows/android-7/samples folder of Android Installation path,

Comment: Mention not, i answered that, bcox m new here, and a friend told me, to Up my reputations, i have to make answers on questions which i know, though this question has been posted a week ago, but for voting up, i have to be in the Market.. :-)